# Hide X-Powered-By (nginx)

Tags: security, nginx

So is there any way to hide X-Powered-By on Nginx?

Comment: x-powered-by is often added by the module for a certain language -- e.g. PHP -- and not the server itself. What value do you have in the header?

Comment: Details, please? Should be closed if you can't supply any details to allow someone to answer.

Comment: -1: This should asked on SF as it is related to the running of servers, not programming.

Comment: @RobertMacLean Agreed, but you can just flag it - I think it should be moved too, but it's a good question.

Answer (score 66):

```
proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
```

Comment: I tried adding it to the http {} section and to the server {} section but it still keeps setting it.

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.14

Comment: Confirmed that works with proxy_pass on nginx/1.1.19. Documentation http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header. No modules or fastcgi in use.

Comment: It's doesn't hide my X-Powered-By header on nginx 1.8.1

Comment: I just tested it, no luck on nginx/1.11.9

Comment: If you use fastcgi, you must use `fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;`.

Answer (score 60):

x-powered-by is given by the module, for instance php fastcgi module offers to set `expose_php=Off`
in php.ini

Comment: dont forget to restart server and php-fpm if you use it

Comment: proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By; in conf doesn't work on nginx/1.11.9 and this solution works. This should be accecpted answer.

Comment: With geerlingguy/ansible-role-php you can use the param: php_expose_php: "Off" (https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-php)

Comment: On ArchLinux I had to restart `php-fastcgi.service` to get this to work.. Thank You.

Answer (score 17):

[`fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_hide_header) or [`proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header) on http/server context

Comment: For PHP-FPM: `fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;` will work.

Answer (score 17):

If you use NGINX with FastCGI you should use:

```
fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
```

Answer (score 5):

### Nginx

1. Open this file

   $ `sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
2. Find the HTTP section, this section defines configurations for Nginx's HttpCoreModule. Add the below directive:

   $ `server_tokens off;`

This will configure Nginx not send any version numbers in the HTTP header.

(Removing the server name is possible, however, since Nginx modules cannot be dynamically loaded, you would need to recompile Nginx from source with the HttpHeadersMoreModule Nginx module.)

3. Reload Nginx configuration
   To apply the change, reload Nginx service:

   $ `sudo service nginx reload`

### PHP

For server security reasons, it is recommended that you disable or hide this information from attackers who might be targeting your server by wanting to know whether you are running PHP or not.

Step 1.

```
$ `sudo nano /etc/php.ini`
```

2. Find the keyword *expose_php* and set its value to *Off*:

   $ `expose_php = off`
3. If you're running PHP as FPM, then you'll need to reload PHP-FPM

   $ `sudo service php-fpm reload`

After reloading, the response header *X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2* should be missing.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the [more_clear_headers directive from the nginx's HttpHeadersMoreModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule#more_clear_headers) which can allow you to declare:

```
more_clear_headers 'X-Powered-By';
```

which should do just what you want.

Comment: This did not work for me, and I believe it requires a source compile for nginx to enable: http://serverfault.com/questions/214242/can-i-hide-all-server-os-info

Answer (score 1):

```
#nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

comment this line

```
more_clear_headers 'X-Powered-By';
```

and restart Nginx