# how to hide php_self

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am running my site on an Apache server with php. I use htaccess to hide informations from the URL and make them look good. But if I check the header of my website in browser, the `php_self` shows the actual path of the file opened. Is there a way to hide it or change its value?

Comment: I don't see `php_self` as a response header for my website (which also uses php/apache/.htaccess to change the url).  Maybe it has to do with your server configuration.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7627713/389755