# expose_php not work (nginx)

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, http-headers

at the first time , i try to use proxy_hide_header to strip it off , but it doesn't work

then I had changed the etc/php.ini , set the expose_php = Off

but the X-Powered-By header just still there

```
root@wordpress:~# ps -ef |grep php | grep -v grep
root     10643     1  0 23:22 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc/php-fpm.conf)                                                                                  
nobody   10644 10643  0 23:22 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www                                                                                                                                 
nobody   10645 10643  0 23:22 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www                                                                                                                                 
root@wordpress:~#
```

my php version is  php 5.3.26

```
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--prefix=/usr/local/php-5.3.26' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc' '--enable-fpm' '--enable-debug' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex' '--with-zlib' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl=/usr/lib/' '--with-readline=/lib' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr/lib' '--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql'

PHP Version => 5.3.26

System => Linux wordpress.ruby-mine.com 3.9.3-x86_64-linode33 #1 SMP Mon May 20 10:22:57 EDT 2013 x86_64
Build Date => Jun 11 2013 21:58:26
Configure Command =>  ./configure  --prefix=/usr/local/php-5.3.26 --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc --enable-fpm --enable-debug --with-openssl --with-pcre-regex --with-zlib --with-bz2 --with-curl=/usr/lib/ --with-readline=/lib --with-libxml-dir=/usr/lib --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc
```

and I also note that , the output of php -i shows that expose_php = on

```
root@wordpress:/usr/local/php/etc# php -i | grep Configuration
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
Configuration
root@wordpress:/usr/local/php/etc# 


root@wordpress:/usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc# ll /usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc/php.ini
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 69628 Jun 11 22:51 /usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc/php.ini
root@wordpress:/usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc#
```

Comment: Have you definitely tried all the solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962230/hide-x-powered-by-nginx

Comment: Do you have some additional config files where it's turned on? (See in /usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc)

Comment: Do `php -i | grep Configuration` to make sure you're editing the right php.ini

Comment: @joe : I try the  'proxy_hide_header' and expose_php.

Comment: @bwoebi : i grep the expose_php , just the the php.ini file has it

Comment: @aynber : yes , /usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc/

Comment: It also says `Loaded Configuration File => (none)` . You said the file is there, so double-check the permissions on the file, and make sure it's readable by all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I got it .

the reason is about the configure options

below is the original configure options

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php-5.3.26 \
             --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc/ \
             --enable-fpm \
             --enable-debug \
             --with-openssl \
             --with-pcre-regex \
             --with-zlib \
             --with-bz2 \
             --with-curl=/usr/lib/ \
             --with-readline=/lib \
             --with-libxml-dir=/usr/lib \
             --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql
```

and I changed to the fowlloing

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php-5.3.26 \
            --sysconfdir=/usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc/ \
             --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc/ \
             --with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc/ \
             --enable-fpm \
             --enable-debug \
             --with-openssl \
             --with-pcre-regex \
             --with-zlib \
             --with-bz2 \
             --with-curl=/usr/lib/ \
             --with-readline=/lib \
             --with-libxml-dir=/usr/lib \
             --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql
```

the problem fixed , now the **Loaded Configuration File** changed from (none) to

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc/
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc/
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/php-5.3.26/etc/php.ini
```

the X-Powered-By header finally gone

thanks for all the guys , especially **aynber**

Answer (score 1):

For me, I found it in my `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` files.

Had to scroll down 300 lines to find the default `expose_php = On` and switch it to `Off`. I changed it in both file locations just to be safe.

Don't forget to run `sudo service php5-fpm restart` after as well!

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble getting expose_php to work with Wordpress on GoDaddy.

Found the solution was to add `expose_php = 0` instead of `expose_php = on` in the `.user.ini` file.

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php default value for expose_php is "1" whereas some others properties are listed as "off" or "on". Maybe there's a peculiarity in GoDaddy where it won't translate "off" to "0".

Comment: same on apache server, thanks